# Post per page not working

Tags: query-posts, get-posts

I have 2 parent categories are app and game. Beside them has child categories.
My code get 6 post from 2 parent categories with orderby post date and order DESC, but post per page not working. Please help me solve this problem.

Here my code :

```
<?php 

$args = array(

'cat'=> 42,
'orderby'          => 'post_date',
'order'            => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => 6,

);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 

$the_query->the_post();

?>
```

Comment: what does not working means? what does the query returns?

Comment: do you have any 'sticky' posts in your site?

Comment: It's show all post of 2 categories, not 6 posts.

Comment: Do you have any plugins that would be changing it? What happens when you `var_dump( $the_query );`?